# Concatenate replacements in printf in bash

Tags: bash, printf

I just want to use the gettext function only with the string that would be replaced later with their corresponding values.

```
printf "$(gettext "Package %b%s %bnot found%b.\n")" "$WC" "$pkg" "$CC" "$NC"
```

In this case I want to resolve first the function of gettext, and then replace its value that could be "Package %b%s %bnot found%b.\n" with the values at right.

The problem is that I would not use the function gettext as first argument of the printf, but I don't know how to avoid this whitout it

Comment: I don't understand the problem, do you get an error, what output do you expect?

Comment: I don't get an error. In fact it works. But printf should not use variables at its first argument so I am asking for a possible solution

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: I think that because of this: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2059

Comment: Do you anticipate gettext putting `%` into your string?

Comment: Exactly. I expect with this to translate the string "Package %b%s %bnot found%b.\n" and then replace the special characters by their variables at right

Comment: Yes , so the `%`s are intentional, so it will work as intended. The only reason to not use a vars in the format section is if you don't have control over what it will contain and can't guarantee unintentional format characters wont be in it.

Comment: Okay, I was not convinced about disabling the warning of shellcheck but you are right!